# How I can solve this problem "System null reference error"

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program obj = new Program();
    Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for PackMan 2 Ghost and 3 for AC FSM");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    //if (input == "1")
    //{
    obj.Packman();
```

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4660142)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question. As posted, there is no obvious NRE.

Answer (score -1):

If you're taking inputs as this

Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for PackMan 2 Ghost and 3 for AC FSM");

Then

You should try using switch case it will work

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    Program obj = new Program();

    Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for PackMan 2 Ghost and 3 for AC FSM");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    Boolean exit= false;

    While(!exit){
        Switch (input)
        {
            case 1 :
                obj.Packman();
                break;
            case 2: 
                break;
            case 3: 
                break;
            case 4:
                Exit= true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When posting code, please format it appropriately so it is easy to read.  Also, make sure it compiles.  Your code as listed does not compile.